# I want to add hidden class every element where hidden class is absent

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

[image]

I can remove hidden class but can't add hidden class at every element.
For first time when i click at organization related sub-organization hidden class removed, but for second time when i click at organization the related sub-organization display along with previous sub-organization. I want to display single origination related sub-organization items only. My code shows all combined sub-organization.

My current code which i use to remove hidden class is given below:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
            var valueis = $('input[name="qOT"]:checked').val();
            

            if (valueis) {
                var org_id = 'org_head' + valueis;
                
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName(org_id);
                var y = x.length;

                alert(y);
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].classList.remove("hide")

                }
```

```html
My Organization code sample given below :
-------------------------------------

<div>
<label id="lbqOT1" class="label_radio r_off" for="qOT1">
<input name="qOT" id="qOT1" value="59" type="radio" data-name="59" class="org_head"><span id="spqOT1">Anti Corruption Commission</span>
</label>
<label id="lbqOT2" class="label_radio r_off" for="qOT2">
<input name="qOT" id="qOT2" value="53" type="radio" data-name="53" class="org_head"><span id="spqOT2">Bangladesh Election Commission</span>
</label>
</div>

   My Sub organization code sample given below :
------------------------------------------

<div id="mCSB_3_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">

<label id="lbqOT1624" class="label_radio organization_select                                         org_head42" for="qOT1624">
                                        <input name="qOT" id="qOT1624" value="Org-658" type="radio" data-ghead="Bangladesh Judicial Service Commission" data-name="Bangladesh Judicial Service Commission" class=""><span id="spqOT1624">Bangladesh Judicial Service Commission</span>
                                    </label>
<label id="lbqOT2054" class="label_radio organization_select                                         org_head43 hidden" for="qOT2054">
                                        <input name="qOT" id="qOT2054" value="Ora-305" type="radio" data-ghead="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission (BERC)" data-name="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission" class=""><span id="spqOT2054">Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission</span>
                                    </label>
<label id="lbqOT3" class="label_radio r_off" for="qOT3">
<input name="qOT" id="qOT3" value="43" type="radio" data-name="43" class="org_head"><span id="spqOT3">Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission (BERC)</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is working

```
var timesClicked = 0;
```

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
var valueis = $('input[name="qOT"]:checked').val();

```
        timesClicked++;

        if (valueis && timesClicked==1) {
            var org_id = 'org_head' + valueis;
            var adCls = 'hide'+ timesClicked;

            var x = document.getElementsByClassName(org_id);
            var y = x.length;

            alert(y);
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("hide");
                x[i].classList.add(adCls);

            } 
            
        }
        else if(valueis && timesClicked>1){
            var org_id = 'org_head' + valueis;
            var minusClick = timesClicked -1;
            var minCls = 'hide'+ minusClick;
            var adCls2 = 'hide'+ timesClicked;

            var x = document.getElementsByClassName(org_id);
            var y = x.length;

            alert(adCls2);
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("hide");
                x[i].classList.add(adCls2);

            } 
            
            var subList = document.getElementsByClassName(minCls); 
            var y1 = subList.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {  
                     
                subList[i].classList.add("hide");
            } 
        }

            else {
                alert('not selected');
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "hide" class to all subcategories where "hide" not exist under all categories before removing current selected category.

Comment: need help with code to select all the sub-organization where hidden class is absent.

Comment: add a common class to all sub category elements                                                   
  ```<input name="qOT" id="qOT2054" value="Ora-305" type="radio" data-ghead="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission (BERC)" data-name="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission" class="sub">                              
        var subList = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');                                
           if(!$("ul").hasClass("class-name")){
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
 }

Answer (score 0):

add a common class to all sub category elements

```
<input name="qOT" id="qOT2054" value="Ora-305" type="radio" data-ghead="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission (BERC)" data-name="Bangladesh Energy Regulatory Commission" class="sub"> 
                           
 var subList = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');    
 for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {  
    if(!subList[i].hasClass("hide")) {  
       subList[i].addClass("hide");  
    }   
}   
var valueis = $('input[name="qOT"]:checked').val();  
if (valueis) {  
   var org_id = 'org_head' + valueis;  
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName(org_id);  
   var y = x.length; 
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
      x[i].classList.remove("hide");  
   }
```

Comment: just skip the if condition and try for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {  subList[i].addClass("hide");  }